# How to get time stamp of database update using psycopg2

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2, comet, postgresql-9.6

I am implementing HTTP streaming with Django. When a user opens a webpage, there is a connection made to the server which returns back data when a new entry is made to the postgresql table.

Let's call the model "M", the model which when updated returns back the data to the client
I have a view `get_update` which does the timestamp checking and returns back data. 
How can I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code it's hard to know, but from what I understand you're trying to query the last time a table was updated. If that's correct, I would just add a "last_updated" attribute on your model and query that, like so:

*models.py*

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

*views.py*

```
def get_update():
    time_updated = YourModel.objects.last().last_updated
    return(time_updated)
```